# i get this window with out any of content why?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

i am looking into the code and i cant figure out what is the problem with this code why the window doesnt show up the content, please help anyone thanks in advance!

i built with netbeans very simple swing app with window builder , and this time it doesnt show the content at all the window is not set right or this is another problem i am busting my mind how to solve this

```html
public class AddCoupon extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JTextField amount;
    private javax.swing.JButton cancel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compName1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compName2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compPass;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compPass1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compPass2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compPass3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel compPass6;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> couponTypes;
    private javax.swing.JTextField endDate;
    private javax.swing.JTextField imgPath;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea massage;
    private javax.swing.JButton okBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField price;
    private javax.swing.JTextField startDate;
    private javax.swing.JTextField title;
 

 public AddCoupon() {
  super("Add Coupon");
  
  try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
      
   }

   /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
    * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents() {

       compName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       compPass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       title = new javax.swing.JTextField();
       startDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
       okBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
       cancel = new javax.swing.JButton();
       jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       endDate = new javax.swing.JTextField();
       compPass1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       amount = new javax.swing.JTextField();
       compPass2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       compName1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       compPass3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       price = new javax.swing.JTextField();
       compName2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
       couponTypes = new javax.swing.JList<>();
       jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
       massage = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
       compPass6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
       imgPath = new javax.swing.JTextField();

       setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setAlwaysOnTop(true);
       setLocation(new java.awt.Point(0, 0));
       compName.setText("Coupon title :");

       compPass.setText("Start Date :");

       startDate.setText("MM/dd/yyyy");

       okBtn.setText("Ok");
       okBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               okBtnActionPerformed(evt);
           }
       });

       cancel.setText("Cancel");
       cancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               cancelActionPerformed(evt);
           }
       });

       jLabel1.setText("Add New Coupon");

       endDate.setText("MM/dd/yyyy");

       compPass1.setText("End Date :");

       compPass2.setText("Massage:");

       compName1.setText("Amount :");

       compPass3.setText("Type");

       compName2.setText("Price :");

       couponTypes.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
   String[] strings = { "blah","blah" };
           public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
           public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
       });
       jScrollPane1.setViewportView(couponTypes);

       massage.setColumns(20);
       massage.setRows(5);
       jScrollPane2.setViewportView(massage);

       compPass6.setText("img path :");

       javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
       getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
       layout.setHorizontalGroup(
           layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
           .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                   .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                       .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                       .addComponent(jLabel1))
                   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                       .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                           .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                           .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                       .addComponent(compName)
                                       .addComponent(compPass)
                                       .addComponent(compPass1))
                                   .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                       .addComponent(endDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                       .addComponent(startDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                       .addComponent(title, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                               .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                       .addComponent(compName1)
                                       .addComponent(compPass3)
                                       .addComponent(compPass2))
                                   .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                       .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                       .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                       .addComponent(amount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                       .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                           .addContainerGap()
                           .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addComponent(compName2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                               .addComponent(compPass6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                           .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                           .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                               .addComponent(price, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                               .addComponent(imgPath, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                           .addGap(2, 2, 2))))
               .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
           .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGap(86, 86, 86)
               .addComponent(okBtn)
               .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
               .addComponent(cancel)
               .addGap(40, 40, 40))
       );
       layout.setVerticalGroup(
           layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
           .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGap(17, 17, 17)
               .addComponent(jLabel1)
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(compName)
                   .addComponent(title, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(compPass)
                   .addComponent(startDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(compPass1)
                   .addComponent(endDate, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(compName1)
                   .addComponent(amount, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                   .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                       .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                       .addComponent(compPass3))
                   .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                       .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                       .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
               .addGap(27, 27, 27)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                   .addComponent(compPass2)
                   .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(price, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                   .addComponent(compName2))
               .addGap(18, 18, 18)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                   .addComponent(compPass6)
                   .addComponent(imgPath, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
               .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
               .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                   .addComponent(okBtn)
                   .addComponent(cancel))
               .addContainerGap())
       );

       pack();
   }// </editor-fold>             

   private void okBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   
  
   }                                     

   private void cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
      dispose();
   }                                      


                
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `ìnitComponents()` within your constructor

```
public AddCoupon() {
    super("Add Coupon");

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddCoupon.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    initComponents();                         <---- HERE
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

---

### OUTPUT

[image]